# WPF Control OverrideMetadata: specify default value to come from resource

Tags: wpf, controls

I would like to specify a resource as a default value for my control for the `BorderBrushProperty`. The reason being the brush is a LinearGradientBrush which I defined in XAML. So I'm looking for something like this in my static CTOR (3rd line):

```
    static Gauge()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof (Gauge), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof (Gauge)));
        BorderThicknessProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof (Gauge), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Thickness(16)));
        BorderBrushProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof (Gauge), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("OuterFrameStroke"));
    }
```

This is what my XAML looks like (in themes\generic.xaml):

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="OuterFrameStroke" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF636060" Offset="1" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FF5F5C5C" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFEEDEDE" Offset="0.35" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFA09595" Offset="0.705" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, should have thought 2 seconds longer. Of course I can set this default property in my template

```
<Style TargetType="gauge:Gauge">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AFD6" Offset="0.321" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.674" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```